# What is the difference btw BehaviorSubject.add and BehaviorSubject.sink.add?

Tags: dart, flutter

In Google I/O 2018 video ([the code](https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments/blob/master/shared/lib/src/bloc/cart_bloc.dart)), it uses `BehaviorSubject.add`.

But in Flutter official recommended article's [code](https://github.com/apatil88/FlutterDartProjects/blob/master/login_navigate_state_mgmt/lib/src/blocs/state_mgmt_bloc.dart), it uses `BehaviorSubject.sink.add`.

Why and What is the difference? and Which one should I use? Or are they the same?

Thanks.